# Show that the maximal ideal space of $l^{\infty}$ is totally disconnected.

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

I have this problem in my operator theory assignment:

Show that the maximal ideal space of $l^{\infty}$ is totally disconnected.

How to approach this . what does it mean to say maximal ideal space is totally disconnected.

What i know is that since $l^{\infty}$ is commutative unital Banach algebra its maximal ideal space is one to one correspondence  with its character space(set of all multiplicative linear functionals)

please provide some  hint.Thanks in Advanced

Answer (score 2):

[Totally disconnected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_disconnected_space) means that the connected components are the single points.

You have that $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)\simeq C(X)$, where $X$ is the maximal ideal space. It is well-known that $X=\beta\mathbb N$, the Stone-Cech compactification of $\mathbb N$, but we don't need that here. What we do need, is that $X$ is Hausdorff and compact, and thus normal (T4).

Let $E\subset X$ be a connected component. Then $E$ is clopen and $1_E$ is continuous. By the above isomorphism, $1_E$ corresponds to some projection $p\in \ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$. This $p$ is necessarily minimal, since any decomposition $p=q+(p-q)$ would imply $1_E=1_F+1_G$ with $F,G$ closed and disjoint, so $E=F\cup G$ with $F,G$ clopen. The projections in $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$ are the sequences of $1$ and $0$, so to be minimal we must have $p=e_j$ for some $j$.

If $E$ is not a single point, let $a,b\in E$ be distinct points. Because $X$ is T4, by Urysohn's Lemma there exists $f\in C(X)$ with $f(a)=1$, $f(b)=0$. Then $g=f\,1_E\in C(X)$. Let $y\in\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$ be the element corresponding to $g$. As $0\leq g\leq 1_E$, we have $0\leq y\leq p=e_j$. But then $y=\alpha p$ for some $\alpha>0$, and thus $g=\alpha 1_E$. But now
$$
1=g(a)=\alpha 1_E(a)=\alpha1_E(b)=g(b)=0,
$$
a contradiction.

It follows that $E$ consists of a single point.

---

**Edit: $X=\beta\mathbb N$.**

The usual way to construct $\beta\mathbb N$ is as the weak$^*$-closure of $\delta(\mathbb N)$, where $\delta:\mathbb N\to C_b(\mathbb N)^*$ is $\delta_n(x)=x_n$. Since $\mathbb N$ is discrete, we have $C_b(\mathbb N)=\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$. If $\gamma\in\beta\mathbb N$, then there exists a net $\{n_j\}_j\subset\mathbb N$ such that $\gamma=\lim_j\delta_{n_j}$; being a limit of characters in a unital C$^*$-algebra, $\gamma$ is also a character. Thus $\beta\mathbb N\subset X$.

It remains to that that $X\setminus\beta\mathbb N=\varnothing$; note that this inclusion occurs in $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)^*$. Let $h\in X\setminus\beta\mathbb N$. By Hahn-Banach (geometric version, with the weak$^*$-topology) there exists $x$ in the weak$^*$-dual of $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)^*$ with $x(h)=1$ and $x|_{\beta\mathbb N}=0$. The weak$^*$ double dual of $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$ is itself (this is true for any locally convex space). So $x\in \ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$, and now we have $h(x)=1$ and $\delta_n(x)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. This is a contradiction, since $\delta_n=0$ for all $n$ means that $x=0$. So $h$ does not exist, and $\beta\mathbb N=X$.

Comment: why is $E$ open set ?it is closed  since it is connected component. but why open ?

Comment: @paarth: I have changed the argument a bit.

Comment: Hi Martin. Sorry for reviving an old post, but I was wondering if you have any links or sources for the fact that $X=\beta \mathbb{N}$? I have been looking but failed to find anything about this.

Comment: I don't know a reference of the top of my head. But I edited a proof in.

Comment: When you show that $X\setminus \beta \mathbb N = \varnothing$, how exactly do you obtain a linear functional from HB that separates $h$ and $\beta \mathbb N$? The version I am aware of separates a point from a ($w^*$-)closed subspace.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosPhoevos: not sure what point is unclear, so please let me know. We have the point $\{h\}$ (that version of HB works for compact sets) and $\beta\mathbb N$ is closed by definition.

Comment: @MartinArgerami   What I mean is that the usual separation theorem I am aware of separates a point $p$ from a closed set $F$ by a functional $f$ in the sense that $f(p)>\sup f[F]$. Now if $F$ is in addition a subspace then $f$ can be chosen so that $f(p)=1$ and $f=0$ on $F$. I think your proof shows that the annihilator of $\{δ_n\}$ is zero so that the span of $δ_n$ are weak star dense in the dual. Not sure how you can use that to show weak-star density of $δ_n$ in $X$.

Comment: My proof does.not show that the annihilator of $\{\delta_n\}$ is zero, as this is trivially true ($\delta_n$ gives the $n^{\rm th}$ coordinate, if all entries of a sequence are zero then the sequence is zero). It shows that $\delta_n(x)=0$ for all $n$ by HB, as you say, so $x=0$, contradicting the fact that $h(x)=1$ and thus showing that it is not possible to separate $h$ and $\beta\mathbb N$. This shows that $\beta\mathbb N$ is dense in $X$, but both sets are closed so they are equal.